# How to dynamically create an object property & assign values using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

Please can someone educate me on how to assign values to object properties correctly in the given scenario:

I am taking the value of a text area, splitting the value at a new line. I need to assign these split values to a property of an object in an array. See below code:

```
var items = [{}];

function process() {
    var i = 0;
    items.forEach((j) => {
        j.self = document.getElementById('input').value.split('\n');
    });
```

process() is called when a button is clicked.

In the console, I get the following:

[image]

Instead of key[0] for example having 10 self values as an array, I need a single value to be assigned to key[0] as the value of the self property. The second split needs to be assigned to key[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLUtb.png).self for example.

Expected output would be like this (apologies if not totally accurate):

```
items[0]{self: split-string[0]},
items[1]{self: split-string[1]},
items[2]{self: split-string[2]},
```

And so forth...

Rather than (what is shown in the console):

```
items[0].self[0] = split-string[0];
items[0].self[1] = split-string[1];
items[0].self[2] = split-string[2];
```

If that makes sense, please can someone assist.

Comment: You're overwriting `j` with `j++`? --- Edit: Why are you using a number and then attaching a property to it?

Comment: Really struggling to see what you're trying to get from the split strings. Can you show your expected output

Comment: @evolutionxbox I removed the j declaration and the j++, still the same output

Comment: Please update the question to show us what's changed?

Comment: @Jamiec I have updated the question, please let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @srcomptn Yep makes sense - exactly what my answer produces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you're trying to get out, but if I understand correctly its an array of objects with a property `self` containing a line from the input.

If that assumption is correct, this should work:

```js
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click",process);

function process(){
    const items = document.getElementById("input").value
                           .split("\n")
                           .map(line => ({self:line}));
    console.log(items);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5">Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4</textarea>
<button id="clickme">Process</button>
```

Comment: Very sorry for my god awful explanation, but this is exactly what I meant. Thank you very much for this

Comment: @srcomptn ha... no probs I sort of got it.